# Is there any way that matlab write the results of calculations in text file?

Tags: matlab

I have simple calculation as below :

```
syms a b c d e f   
A = [a,b;c,d;e,f];  
B = pinv(A);
```

Is there any way that matlab write the results  of calculations in .m file or text file?

Comment: Matlab can write results to .MAT files, the .M files are for scripts/functions.

Comment: @Allen: Please explain what output do you expect.

Comment: I want the results save in text file.I've used:  "  the save array_data1.out A -ascii;
type array_data1.out
dlmwrite('array_data2.out', A, ' '); but I got the error "Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs.

Error in dlmwrite (line 189)
                    str = sprintf('%.*g%+.*gi',precn,real(m(i,j)),precn,imag(m(i,j)));

Error in DSDX (line 210)
dlmwrite('array_data2.out',B, ' ');"
type array_data2.out

Comment: Any specific format for the output?

Comment: text file or other type like excel that I can read an use it

Comment: @Allen You should edit your updates into the original question rather than putting them in comments. It's easier to have all of the information in one place plus, as you see, formatting in comments is atrocious.

Comment: I've mentioned in my question but perhaps you didn't read it well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sym/char` function converts a `sym` object to MuPad code, which can be written to a text file:

```
fid=fopen('symeq.txt','w+')
fwrite(fid,char(B))
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

For .m file you can use below code

```
fid=fopen('Amfile.m','r+')
fwrite(fid,char(A))
fclose(fid);
fid=fopen('Bmfile.m','r+')
fwrite(fid,char(B))
fclose(fid);
```